# Get number of fields in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get number of fields(сolumns) in mysql table with PHP or just some kind of mysql query? Is there a way to do this without `SELECT * FROM table_name` and `mysql_num_fields()`? Maybe there is a way with one mysql query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalColumns
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  table_name = 'table1' AND 
       TABLE_SCHEMA = 'databaseName'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d992/3)

Answer (score 5):

Use the below query to get no of fields in table,

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
  AND table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1858864 All the above answers are fine but I just wanted to give it to you in php using pdo .
And I did up vote your question and their answers because  everything seems  to be relevant to me 
A big thanks to @JW. For editing

```
<?php
try {
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf-8','root','');
} catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Connection failed'.$e->getMessage();
}
#count in pdo 
$count = ("SELECT count(*) FROM  table_name ");
$result =$con->prepare($count);
$result->execute();
$number= $result->fetchColumn();
echo  $number;
#count in pdo  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $query = "select book_name from tbllibrary "; $result = mysql_query($query);
            //while loop to display mysql table field values in html text boxes

            $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $count = count($row);
                    $y = 0;
                    while ($y < $count)
                    {
                        $c_row = current($row);
                        next($row);
                        $y = $y + 1;
                    }               
                        $book_name=$c_row;$i = $i + 1;
                    }

echo 'There are ' . $i. ' books available in the Library</p>';
```

Here the variable i will store total no.of columns for the row named book_name. You can also use the variable $book name for the future use but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name
```